# get Nth line in file after parsing another file

Tags: bash, shell, unix, csh

I have one of my large file as

**`foo:43:sdfasd:daasf

   bar:51:werrwr:asdfa

   qux:34:werdfs:asdfa

   foo:234:dfasdf:dasf

   qux:345:dsfasd:erwe

   ...............`**

here 1st column foo, bar and qux etc. are file names. and 2nd column 43,51, 34 etc. are line numbers. I want to print Nth line(specified by 2nd column) for each file(specified in 1st column).
How can I automate above in unix shell.
Actually above file is generated while compiling and I want to print warning line in code.

-Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

```
while IFS=: read name line rest
do
    head -n $line $name | tail -1
done < input.txt
```

Comment: If you only want the line in question: `head -n $line $name | tail -1`

Answer (score 2):

```
while IFS=: read file line message; do
    echo "$file:$line - $message:"
    sed -n "${line}p" "$file"
done <yourfilehere
```

Comment: for efficiency: `sed -n "${line}{p;q}"`

Comment: It is a good practice to save IFS before changing it and restore to it's original state after it is no longer needed. Like: `OFS=$IFS; ...; IFS=$OFS`

Comment: vyegorov: the above only changes it for the duration of the read command.  Even inside the body of the loop, it's back to its default value.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'NR==4 {print}' yourfilename

or

cat yourfilename | awk 'NR==4 {print}'
```

The above one will work for 4th line in your file.You can change the number as per your requirement.

Comment: to pass the line number: `awk -v n=$lineno 'NR==n {print;exit}' file`

Comment: If the file is getting processed in the middle of another then we should use -v option.But if its an explicit process then we donot require -v option.

Answer (score 0):

```
 sed -nr '3{s/^([^:]*):([^:]*):.*$/\1 \2/;p}' namesNnumbers.txt 
 qux 34
```

- -n no output by default,
- -r regular expressions (simplifies using the parens)
- in line 3 do {...;p} (print in the end)
- s ubstitute foobarbaz with foo bar

So to work with the values:

```
fnUln=$(sed -nr '3{s/^([^:]*):([^:]*):.*$/\1 \2/;p}' namesNnumbers.txt)

fn=$(echo ${fnUln/ */})
ln=$(echo ${fnUln/* /})
sed -n "${ln}p" "$fn"
```

Comment: The question is asking how to get line 34 out of file "qux" (and similarly for all the other lines)

Comment: @glennjackman: I know. With "qux" and "34" it is trivial: `sed -n "${lineno}p" "$filename"`. You think I should include this in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Just in awk, but probably worse performance than answers by @kev or @MarkReed.
However it does process each file just once. Requires GNU awk

```
gawk -F: '
    BEGIN {OFS=FS}
    { 
        files[$1] = 1
        lines[$1] = lines[$1] " " $2
        msgs[$1, $2] = $3 
    }
    END {
        for (file in files) {
            split(lines[file], l, " ")
            n = asort(l)
            count = 0
            for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
                while (++count <= l[i])
                    getline line < file
                print file, l[i], msgs[file, l[i]]
                print line
            }
            close(file)
        }
    }
'
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
sed 's/^\([^,]*\),\([^,]*\).*/sed -n "\2p" \1/' file |
sort -k4,4 | 
sed ':a;$!N;s/^\(.*\)\(".*\)\n.*"\(.*\)\2/\1;\3\2/;ta;P;D' |
sh
```